# Is there a way I could read and update values from html attributes in node js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, jsdom

I want to use the `date-holidays` npm package to check for holidays between two given dates and also a custom function to check for weekends and then subtract the two from the number of days between the two dates so that I can return the number of available workdays.
So far I have created the functions using hardcoded dates and it works perfectly in the console but I don't know how to read the date-values from the HTML file using `onchange()` and use them to get the remaining days then and then update the value of the remaining days on the HTML page before submitting the form. I tried using `document.getElementbyId()` but found out that node.js doesn't support DOM.
How can I get around this?

The code:

```js
var Holidays = require('date-holidays')
var hd = new Holidays()
var countries = hd.getCountries() // get supported countries
hd.init('KE')                     // get kenyan Holidays for the current year


function getFormated_StartDate(){
    var start_hol = new Date("11/30/2021");
    var dd = String(start_hol.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    var mm = String(start_hol.getMonth()+1).padStart(2, '0');
    var yyy= start_hol.getFullYear();
    start_hol = new Date(mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyy);

    return start_hol;
}

function getFormated_EndDate(){
    var end_hol = new Date("12/28/2021");
    var dd = String(end_hol.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    var mm = String(end_hol.getMonth()+1).padStart(2, '0');
    var yyy= end_hol.getFullYear();
    end_hol = new Date(mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyy);

    return end_hol;
}

function getTimeDifference(){
    var a = getFormated_StartDate();
    var b = getFormated_EndDate();
    var Diff_in_tym = b.getTime() - a.getTime();

    return Diff_in_tym;
}

function getDifferenceInDays(){
    var i = getTimeDifference();
    var Diff_in_days = i / (1000 * 3600 * 24);

    return Diff_in_days;
}

function getWeekendsAndHolidays(){
    var overall_days = 0;
    var start = getFormated_StartDate();
    var end = getFormated_EndDate();

    for (var d = new Date(start); d <= end; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
        var check_hol = hd.isHoliday(d);
                //                        both                               ||        holiday_only       ||              weekend_only
        if( ( (check_hol != false) && (d.getDay() == 6 || d.getDay() == 0) ) || (check_hol != false) || (d.getDay() == 6 || d.getDay() == 0) ){
            overall_days = overall_days + 1;
        // console.log(d.toDateString());
        }
    }
    return overall_days;

}


function getSundaysAndHolidays(){
    var total_days = 0;
    var Start = getFormated_StartDate();
    var End = getFormated_EndDate();

    for (var d = new Date(Start); d <= End; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
        var check_hol = hd.isHoliday(d);
                //                        both                  ||        holiday_only       ||    sundays_only
        if( ( (check_hol != false) && (d.getDay() == 0) ) || (check_hol != false) || ( d.getDay() == 0) ){
            total_days = total_days + 1;
        // console.log(d.toDateString());
        }
    }
    return total_days;
}

function getWorkingDaysIncludingSundays(){
    var sundaysAndHolidays = getSundaysAndHolidays();
    var DifferenceInDays = getDifferenceInDays();
    var workingDaysIncludingSundays = DifferenceInDays - sundaysAndHolidays;

    return workingDaysIncludingSundays;
}

function getWorkingDays(){
    var weekendsAndHolidays = getWeekendsAndHolidays();
    var differenceInDays = getDifferenceInDays();
    var workingDays = differenceInDays - weekendsAndHolidays;

    return workingDays;
}



var z = getWorkingDays();
var Z = getWorkingDaysIncludingSundays();
console.log(z + "\n" + Z);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="./redefine.js"></script>
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <h3 class="container display-5">

       <p class="text-info">Working Days </p> 
      </h3>
<h3></h3>

<section class="container" style="padding-top: 5%; padding-left: 5%;">
 
    

    <form NAME="myForm" Action="" METHOD="GET" >
        <div class="form-row">
            <label for="start_day" class="form-group">Enter the Start Date: <br>
                <input type="date" name="start_day" id="start" required pattern="\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"> <br>
                <span class="validity"></span>
              </label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <label for="end_day" class="form-group">Enter the End Date:<br>
                <input type="date" name="end_day" id="end" required pattern="\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"><br>
                <span class="validity"></span>
              </label>
        </div>

        
        

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" NAME="button" Value="Calculate" onClick="getWorkingDays(this.form)">
          Calculate</button>
        <br>
        <br>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="results" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Available workdays :</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="static" value="0">        
            </div>
          </div>


      </form>

</section>

   
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, it sounds like you don't understand that your nodejs server runs in a completely separate network and computer from the HTML page and its Javascript which runs in the browser (on the end-user's computer).  The two are completely separate.  This is what is known as the client/server architecture.  The server cannot directly access the running HTML page in the browser.

To use the `change` event in your HTML page to validate a value on your server, you would need to send an Ajax call (an http network request) to your server with the new data and ask your server if that data is valid.  Your web page will then get the result back from that web page and can then act accordingly.

To support the Ajax call for this particular validation call, you would create a new route on your nodejs server specifically for this operation.

---

Or, if what you want to do in the `change` event does not need to talk to your server, then you can just add Javascript directly to your web page, get the new value from the `change` event and then (from entirely within the  web page), decide what modifications or checks you want to do in the current web page.